# componentDidMount not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie in ReactJS, trying to fetch data from back-end using API, API and back-end working well, but no data listing in React, where was my mistake ?

Using isomorphic-fetch for fetching. also I looking for a good React, API CRUD blog, please guide me

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      blogPosts: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/view', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'CORS'
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          blogPosts: data
        })
      }).catch(err => err);
  }
  render() {
    return (
 <div>
  <table className="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Options</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      {this.state.blogPosts && this.state.blogPosts.map(post => { return (
      <tr key={post._id}>
        <td>{post._id}</td>
        <td>{post.title}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      ); })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `.catch(err => { console.log({ err }) }` to see if your fetch request is throwing any errors. You're currently doing nothing with the error, so I presume you request is either failing or taking a while to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure the data you get from backend is array of obects?

Comment: yes..   like this {"_id":"5bc42593eebeac0ae724bb05","title":"sss","body":"fsfs","__v":0}

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value 'CORS' is not a valid enum value of type RequestMode

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! About your second question, You cant ask for recommendations here

Comment: @DarkSuniuM okey , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in CORS, so please try this  '`CORS`' to '`cors`'

Comment: yes, working :) what is the difference  ?